# Is there a nation-based (as opposed to topic-based) Stack Exchange site?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I see Stack Exchange sites about languages, about travelling etc, but I'd like to ask (and answer) things about history, culture, habits or other stuff concerning specific country (e.g. Czech SE, UK, [Liberland](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberland)).

Is it plausible on SE? Do you thing there shall be a separate category for that?

Comment: I think you should visit Area 51 to see if any such sites have been previously proposed.

Answer (score 7):

No, and there's not likely to be.

There was once a [proposed "India" site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/40807/india), which would be exactly what you describe. However, it was closed because it's very difficult to be an expert on India, whereas being an expert on, say, Indian law was comparably easy.

A much fuller description of the reasons is in [podcast 51](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/08/podcast-51-the-return-of-codinghorror/).

Answer (score 3):

You could, if you have an idea, [just propose a site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/).

However, I don't think we should get into this 'nation-based' sites. What I like about the current model is that subjects are easier to group than nations. Questions about the topology of a country isn't the same as a question about the language. It are two different disciplines.

If you have a question to compare two countries for example, where would it fit? On the one country's site or the other one? If the sites are grouped on subject, you don't have this issue.